# How to check whether a the program has created a file in the past

Tags: c++

So, I have created a program that creates a separate file for every individual student to store his data. I have set a bool variable to restrict accessing data without entring it but it only allows me to get data if I stored it first while I run the program but I restart the program multiple times which means it won't let me get data if I entered it in the previous run as it thinks that I never entered the data. So I want to add a simple (strictly) function/check that checks whether a file was created in the past (in the previous run) or not if yes then it should let me access that data and (if possible) tell me the name of the file so that I can easily access it and if not then it should give me the default error that I coded.

```
    if (first_entry == false)
    {
        cout << "Enter data first.\n";
        system("pause");
        goto main;
    }
```

Also, I am using switch statements so in case 1: I ask for data also making >> first_entry = true.
In case 2: I have the check that I have mentioned above if true it displays data from the desired file.

Comment: As well the description of the problem as the presence of a `goto ` lead me to suspect that your program has pretty serious structural issues. I encourage you to take a step back and have a "higher level look" at what you're writing. Probably the answer will come automatically.

Comment: If you need to keep info between run, you have to save it in files/database or equivalent.

Comment: I am a beginner so I used goto just for fun I can amend that no problem and I don't know how to save info between run into files or database that's why I have asked the question.

Comment: Why don't you just check whether the file is there?

Comment: Well, that's the part I am trying to ask and solve.

Comment: "I used goto just for fun" Does your idea of fun include having no idea as to what your program *actually does*?

Comment: I just searched it after the first comment that it shouldn't be used. Moreover, I didn't want to use a while loop etc., and I didn't know an alternative to >> goto function so I used it instead. I already mentioned that I will change it so I would request that leave the goto line and suggest a solution that is simple to understand as I already mentioned that I am a beginner not a professional. It was nice to know that some things are bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to check if file exists. You will have to know **it's name** first, though. I guess that since you have some files already created, then you have your data stored in some sort of array / other structure and based on that you can guess the name of the file.

Anyways, here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
...

fstream file;
file.open("directory/your_file.txt", ios::in); //this is where you 
                                               //need to know the filename

if(file.good()) // <-- if file stream returns 'goodbit' iostate
                // which means "does this file open and contain some data"
{
    /* handle data */
}
```

You can find more about `good()` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/).

---

Since you already use `system()`, you can also echo out content of directory
using basic windows shell commands, but it seems to be a workaround-like bad solution.

Comment: I did not use array I used the following code to create a file for every student within a do-while loop so if the user wants to input data of more students he just has to continue the do-while loop and when he is done exit it. The following code is what I used to create files for every student.
...
cin >> roll_no;
ofstream Student_Archive;
Student_Archive(to_string(roll_no) + ".txt");
...
after that to print from or store data to that file I used standard commands.

Comment: Also what if I don't know the file name at such point then is there a way to make the program print the file name that it created earlier. I was thinking to make another file that i should mention in the program so that in a scenario where I don't the file name I can just print data from that file and see which other files were created earlier.